# How to debug gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm migrating to electric and i have some issues setting my gazebo simulation on, i can launch gazebo and my .world map and i seem to works fine (i had to make some changes to remove some errors but in this moment all seem to work fine) now i'm including my robot into the simulation, the problems is that i try to mimic the pr2 launch file to load the world and the robot, but when gazebo start, loads the world and then anything happen... it doesn't fail but also it doesn't load my robot model, i don't know where is stall...

is there some way to run gazebo in "debug" mode to see what is happening?, or is a way to add some lines in the xml/launchs files to print messages? or is there any file that gazebo should write the issues (different that /tmp/gazebo*) ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12435/how-to-debug-gazebo/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could launch Gazebo in GDB to debug. Follow [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) tutorial to do so.

You could also try setting the Gazebo logger level to DEBUG to see if it's printing any debug messages. See [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6